# Agile and smart switch from SVN to GIT and files from many revisions on production

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration, git-svn

We're trying to migrate one of our old projects from `SVN` to `GIT`. It's still in maintaining and development phase and there is of course `git-svn` to do the switch quick and painless, buth there's one problem:

- someone who initiated the project configured `svn` to work on **single**
  branch (there is no directory structure from branches, tags and
  trunk)
- there are two servers - `test` that always has newest revision
  checked out, and `production`, which has **most** of files from revision x,
  and **some** files from revisions y, z and so on.

Is there any way to quickly migrate our project without unwanted downtime and without spending dozens of hours to check which file should be of what revision and setting it manually? There is more than 10000 files, so doing this manually is pure madness.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you taking a look on [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) which allows you to create git-repo from your svn-repo with less effort. It allows you to specify the revisions you'd like to import.

The key feature - i guess - will be, that you're able to keep your svn runnning as master (and the git-repo up to date) until you switched necessary parts of your infrastructure to git.